# Low res audio icon Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, icons, gnome-shell

Upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, and loving the new design. Though there is one big eyesore since install:

[image: Ugh, low res audio]

I can't seem to pinpoint where this image comes from. Can anybody tell me where/how to replace it?

Comment: upgraded from 16.04?? or fresh install??

Comment: what is your present icon theme.. can you share?

Answer (score 0):

if its a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and what ever the icon theme you use those come by default here is the path

```
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/devices/
```

here is the folder in my Ubuntu 18.04
[image]

i have re-placed my customized icons in place of those 4 icons. and below is the result when i increase the volume level.

[image]

if you use different custom icon themes (those are not installed by fresh install of Ubuntu), and if that theme has specifically have these four icons, `audio-volume-high-symbolic.svg` and other 3. then they will be used, other wise above path is used.

in your case, you can simply search for the icon that is bothering you in the above path or in your custom icon theme and put your own icon.

i am using 2 customized icon themes like in below.. one is having those 4 icons and other one not.

[image]

Comment: The default install of Ubuntu does not use Adwaita as the theme.